# Multiple build pipelines triggered when a tag is pushed

Tags: build, azure-devops, continuous-integration, yaml, azure-pipelines

I have created multiple build pipelines in Azure DevOps for different branches in a repository.
My intention is to trigger each pipeline when a specific tag is pushed.
The tag is structured in a way that it is unique for each pipeline.
Example :

```
--MyRepository
 |
 --master
 |
 --ops
 |
 --dev
 |
 --qa
```

A build pipeline for dev,ops and qa each:

- `dev` should be triggered when iff `dev-v*` is pushed
- `ops` should be triggered when iff `ops-v*` is pushed
- `qa` should be triggered when iff `qa-v*` is pushed

Here's what my yaml file looks like(similar ones for the other pipelines):

```yaml
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
      - refs/tags/ops-v*
    exclude:
      - refs/tags/qa*
      - refs/tags/dev*
stages:
- stage: Init
  jobs:
  - job: CheckoutInit
    steps:
    - checkout: self
    - script: *do something*
```

Now what happens when I push say *dev-v1.0.0* is that all the the pipelines are triggered although only the dev pipeline should start. What am I doing wrong or is it something I am overlooking?
Any help is greatly appreciated. Cheers!
Note : I am fairly new to working with Azure Devops.

Comment: Are you sure? I just checked and above pipeline was only triggered for `ops-v1.0.0`, but not for `dev-v1.0.0`.

Comment: Hey, yes I am sure. I can attach a screenshot if it helps.

Comment: Hi @Roy. Is there any update about this ticket? Feel free to let me know if the answer could give you some help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on my test, your Yaml triggers could be right.

I could reproduce the similar issue when the yaml files have the same name in each branch.

For example:

```
--MyRepository
 |
 --master
 |
 --ops
   -- azure-pipelines.yml
 |
 --dev
   -- azure-pipelines.yml
 |
 --qa
  -- azure-pipelines.yml
```

So you could check if the yaml files have the same name.

To solve this issue, you could change each Yaml file name and make sure that they are unique.

```
--MyRepository
 |
 --master
 |
 --ops
   -- azure-pipelines-ops.yml
 |
 --dev
   -- azure-pipelines-dev.yml
 |
 --qa
  -- azure-pipelines-qa.yml
```

Then you need to create new pipelines with the yaml file(new name) again.

Comment: This worked for me. A rookie mistake indeed. Thanks for the fix!